# Does Handler work between processes?

Tags: java, android

**In RemoteService (separate process)**

```
 catch (ConnectException c) {
                TweetViewActivity.h.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
```

**TweetViewActivity**

```
    static public Handler h;

     class LooperThread extends Thread {
          public Handler mHandler;

          public void run() {
              Looper.prepare();
              h = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
                @Override
                public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "handleMessage");
                    return true;
                }
            });
              Looper.loop();
          }
      }
```

While does this code doestn't get control?

```
Log.e("TAG", "handleMessage");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work. Static data is process-local, as is ordinary heap-allocated data.

You want to either use an Intent, or, since you're already doing cross-process comms via the service's IBinder, extend RemoteService's aidl to include a callback interface.